# C# DataTable column already exists issue

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I'm attempting to import a CSV file into a DataTable, however the CSV contains headers that are the same. (For example, there are multiple "Date" headers for different form sections). To fix this, I decided to create a loop that will run through the headers and replace the duplicates or unwanted entries based on their position. I've replaced my replaceWith array with dummy entries, but my actual code does have the correct size to correlate with the replace array.

```
string[] columnNames = null;
        string[] oStreamDataValues = null;
        int[] error = {0,1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,15,21,34,37,57,61,65,68,69,71,75,79,82,83,85,89,93,96,97,99,103,107,110,111,113,117,121,124,125,127,128,129,130,132,182,210,212,213,214,215,216,222,226,239};
        int[] replace = {14,16,17,17,20,23,24,27,28,29,31,32,44,58,59,60,62,63,64,66,67,70,72,73,74,76,77,78,80,81,84,86,87,88,90,91,92,94,95,98,100,101,102,104,105,106,108,109,112,114,115,116,118,119,120,122,123,126,134,136,138,140,142,144,146,148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,170,172,174,176,178,180,184,186,187,188,190,191,192,194,195,196,198,199,200,202,203,204,206,207,208,209,236,242,243,244};
        string[] replaceWith = {"Replace 1", "Replace 2", "Replace 3"};
        string fix = "ignore_";
        int inc = 00;
        string entry = "";
        while (!oStreamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string oStreamRowData = oStreamReader.ReadLine().Trim();
            if (oStreamRowData.Length > 0)
            {
                //oStreamDataValues = Regex.Split(oStreamRowData, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
                oStreamDataValues = oStreamRowData.Split(',');
                if (rowCount == 0)
                {
                    rowCount = 1;
                    columnNames = oStreamDataValues;

                        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < error.Length; j++)
                            {
                                if (error[j] == i)
                                {
                                    entry = fix + inc++;


                                }
                            }
                            for (int k = 0; k < replace.Length; k++)
                            {

                                if (replace[i] == i)
                                {
                                    int add = 0;
                                    entry = replaceWith[add++];
                                }
                            }


                        DataColumn oDataColumn = new DataColumn(entry, typeof(string));
                        oDataColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;
                        oDataTable.Columns.Add(oDataColumn);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm no coding expert, so my syntax/decision making isn't perfect.

However the error that I get is that A column named 'ignore_4' already belongs to this DataTable.

I assume something is incorrect in my loop logic.

Comment: Could you explain what the numbers in the array _error_ and in the array _replace_ mean?

Comment: The array error represent the position number within the CSV file (in this case columnNames) that I want to replace with "ignore_". The replace array represents the position number within columnNames that I wish to replace with a replaceWith array value.

Comment: So when it gets to error[1] which's value is 1, the code would replace columnNames[1] with ignore_01

Answer (score 0):

I think you have overcomplicated the loops. You just need to keep an index of the current position in the array of errors and array of replaces.

```
string rep = "replace_";  // base string for replace fields
string fix = "ignore_";   // base string for ignore fields

// For demonstation purpose I have commented out this array. If you 
// want every 'replace' column have its specific name then prepare this
// array with exactly the number of names required by the number of 
// elements in the replace array
//
// string[] replaceWith = {"Replace 1", "Replace 2", "Replace 3"};

int idxErrors = 0;        // Current position in the error array
int idxReplace = 0;       // Current position in the replace array
int fixCounter = 1;
int repCounter = 1;
string entry = "";
for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
{
    // Is this the index of a column that should be ignored?
    if (idxErrors < error.Length && i == error[idxErrors])
    {
        entry = fix + fixCounter.ToString("D2");
        idxErrors++;
        fixCounter++;
    }
    // Is this the index of a column that should have a different name??
    else if (idxReplace < replace.Length && i == replace[idxReplace])
    {
        entry = rep + repCounter.ToString("D2");
        // entry = replaceWith[repCounter];
        idxReplace++;
        repCounter++;
    }
    else
        entry = columnNames[i];

    // Now create the column
    DataColumn oDataColumn = new DataColumn(entry, typeof(string));
    oDataColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;
    oDataTable.Columns.Add(oDataColumn);
}
```

In this example I have used the same pattern used for the ignored column also for the columns that need to have the name changed. If you want to give each renamed column a proper name, then you need to prepare an array with these proper names and this array should be of the same length of the replace array. Then use the `idxReplace` to take the correct name from the array of possible proper names.